# Blazor WASM OIDC stating that redirect uri is undefined whatever I do

Tags: c#, blazor, openid-connect, webassembly

So, I followed the guidelines in the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) and this [Medium article](https://medium.com/@marcodesanctis2/securing-blazor-webassembly-with-identity-server-4-ee44aa1687ef) which propose that adding OIDC authentication to a Blazor WASM application should be easy as pie.

I already have a working OIDC-Server (Keycloak) which I have used for several Blazor Server applications successfully.

I then defined the needed properties in `appsettings.json` like this:

```
{
  "OIDC": {
    "Authority": "https://mykeycloakserver/auth/realms/master/",
    "ClientId": "MyClientId",
    "ClientSecret": "FooBarBaz-813361955dc3",
    "DefaultScopes": [
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "roles",
      "offline_access"
    ],
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "/",
    "ResponseType": "code"
  }
}
```

and added this to `program.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("OIDC", options.ProviderOptions);
});
```

Application (and server API) starts, I click on Login and am greeted with this message:

[image: error message]

It then does not matter whether I define the `RedirectUri` through `appsetting.json` or explicitly in `program.cs` like this:

```
options.ProviderOptions.RedirectUri = "https://localhost:7066/authentication/login-callback";
```

It always tells me that it's undefined. Setting a breakpoint after the configuration bind tells me that my settings are indeed picked up!

[image]

The complete `program.cs`:

```
using MyWASM.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("AnliegenWASM.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

// Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("MyWASM.ServerAPI"));

builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("OIDC", options.ProviderOptions);
    //options.ProviderOptions.RedirectUri = "https://localhost:7066/authentication/login-callback";
});

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

So, what am I missing?

Comment: Who is thowing the can't read RedirectUrl? your blazor app or KeyCloack? How is the redirectUri configured in keycloak? Also, in general it can be easier to configure AddOpenIDConnect in code instead of Json , then you can remove JSON typing errors from the equation.

Comment: I pretty sure the OIDC server has to be configured with the client and return address as well maybe this is where the error is.

Comment: No, it isn't where the error is. The Redirect Uri is well defined on the Keycloak Server. This is a client-side error message,
If it was an error of the server the _server_ would tell me itself.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this problem. Double check the index.html page where the JS AuthenticationService is added.

I had it referencing the MSAL auth service:

```
<script src="_content/Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
```

When it should have been:

```
<script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
```