# Error using MSAL on Blazor WASM Hosted prerender

Tags: azure-ad-msal, blazor-webassembly, msal.js, blazor-hosted

I'm using a basic Blazor WASM ASPNET Core Hosted WebAssemblyPrerendered .NET 6 app. However, when I try to try to login, I get the following.

`There was an error trying to log you in: 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'redirectUri')'`

Any ideas as to what the issue could be?

Comment: I think this is the same problem as
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70351727/blazor-wasm-oidc-stating-that-redirect-uri-is-undefined-whatever-i-do/71126933#71126933